# How to append to each column of empty pandas data frame different size of lists in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Hi guys this is getting frustrating.! After long hours of online browsing. I can not find a single source that can help here. How to append to each column of empty pandas data frame different size of lists? For instance, I have these three variables:

```
var1 = ['BBCL15', 'KL12TT', 'TMAA03', '1523FR']
var2 = [253, 452, 16]
var3 = ['23n2', 'akg_9', '12.3bl', '30x2', 'dd91']
```

And I would like to append it to empty pandas data frame in a loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

# something like this.
for x in var1:
    df['col1'].append(pd.Series(x), ignore_index=True)

for x in var2:
    df['col2'].append(pd.Series(x), ignore_index=True)

for x in var3:
    df['col3'].append(pd.Series(x), ignore_index=True)
```

Where each variable correspond to a single column and fill in empties spaces with NaN as length of variables is not the same.
Can someone help with this?

Comment: `df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x, columns=[f'col{i}']) for i, x in enumerate([var1, var2, var3], 1)], axis=1)` ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, this one is practical solution!

```
mydict = {'col1': var1, 'col2': var2, 'col3': var3}
df = pd.DataFrame({key:pd.Series(value) for key, value in mydict.items()})
df
```

```
     col1   col2    col3
0   BBCL15  253.0   23n2
1   KL12TT  452.0   akg_9
2   TMAA03   16.0   12.3bl
3   1523FR   NaN     30x2
4    NaN     NaN     dd91
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
>>> max_len = max([len(var1), len(var2), len(var3)])
>>> for col, var in zip(cols, [var1, var2, var3]):
...     df[col] = var+([None]*(max_len - len(var)))
>>> df
     col1   col2    col3
0  BBCL15  253.0    23n2
1  KL12TT  452.0   akg_9
2  TMAA03   16.0  12.3bl
3  1523FR    NaN    30x2
4    None    NaN    dd91
```

Comment: Thanks man! You are a star! Kind regards

Comment: It's interesting how we do exactly the same thing for such an easy task, and yet our code looks totally different :-D

Comment: You're right, we can do same thing in multiple ways, but each implementation has it's pros and cons.

Comment: Check your python and packages version

Comment: I've tested on `Python=3.8.10` and `pandas=1.3.4`

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of lists to use list comphrehensions:

```
lists = [var1, var2, var3]
```

Get the length of the longesst list:

```
longest_length = max([len(v) for v in lists])
```

Pad the lists as required:

```
padded_lists = [v + [float("NaN")]*(longest_length - len(v)) for v in lists]
```

Create the data frame:

```
pd.DataFrame(padded_lists).T
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using `pd.concat` :

```
var1 = ['BBCL15', 'KL12TT', 'TMAA03', '1523FR']
var2 = [253, 452, 16]
var3 = ['23n2', 'akg_9', '12.3bl', '30x2', 'dd91']


df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in [var1, var2, var3] :
  df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(i)], axis = 1, ignore_index  = True)
  
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
```

Note: avoid naming the data frame columns in the first place when you are using this solution.